# Bootstrap Framework with Full-Width Video Header, Mp4 video in video header loads too long

Tags: html, css, performance, video

I have used Bootstrap to build a website for a customer with an mp4 video running in a full-width header. The video (3MB; a placeholder) is working but it takes too long to load. I compressed the video to 1MB without visible quality loss but that made the problem even worse. I need a way to autostart the video without loading time. Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

DEMO: http://ze-q.dizedesign.de/wn00152/

CODE:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

video {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  object-position:center;
}
```

```html
<video poster="" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
<source src="assets/vid/header.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="assets/vid/header.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please edit your question to use the smallest amount of code possible to replicate or demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Oh ok sorry, i will change that

Comment: May be you have bad internet speed, because I see that video loads immediately.

Comment: @Olga I don't think that's the issue - I have pretty good internet and first viewing for me took 15 seconds(!!) on Internet Explorer

Comment: I've just checked one more time in IE11. Video loads immediately. (But it is not 100% full-screen in IE)

Comment: On my Notebook and Smartphone this Video loads fast, but on the Notebook from my Customer, its loads Sadly Slow, he have an MacBook Pro with 100mbit DSL.

Comment: @Olga i think its not 100% Fullscreen because i didnt use a Media Tag on Hero.css for youre Screen width